# How to use the asp.net membership on windows azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, azure, asp.net-membership

I installed universal service provider. I deployed my mvc-3 application on windows azure in staging environment and also created the sql server and sql database on the windows azure. Now I want to use the asp.net default membership option in my application on windows azure. Can anyone please guid me how can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use the membership features of ASP.NET with SQL Azure you'll need to use the [ASP.NET Universal Providers](http://nuget.org/packages/System.Web.Providers). Scott Hanselman has written an introduction on his [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx).

Note that this question has been answered many times before on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342055/asp-net-mvc3-azure-do-i-need-membership-provider-stored-procedures). The next time you want to ask a question I suggest you do a quick search, chance is that you'll already find the question with the appropriate answer.